# mysql_query help

Tags: mysql, select

I have products database like:

```
id: 5
catid: 2,4,26,33,46
name: product one
etc...
```

For each store product `catid` stores multiple categories id separated with commas as one product might appear in several categories.
How can I view the products from for example category with id 26?

My first idea was:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid LIKE '%26%'");
```

but its not working well as it also shows products from 2 and 46 category.

Comment: You should never put more than one piece of data into a column with a database. Take a look at [database normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should consider using a link table between your categories and products, and use a MySQL [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function: `SELECT * FROM products where FIND_IN_SET(26, catid) > 0`

Comment: Thank you very very much, this worked just as needed. Thank you for your fast answer.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql find_in_set() function will do this.

However, it will never be fast.  Mysql indices are not useful for finding a match in the middle of a string.  They only work if you're matching against the whole string, or a substring starting from the beginning.  A full scan of the data will be required for every query.

If you're not too far along in development, and can change the data model to use a mapping table that looks something like:

```
create table product_cat (
  rel_id primary key,
  product_id int,
  cat_id int,
  unique (product) product_id,
  index (cat_product) cat_id, product_id
)
```

Then, put a row in the table for each category/product relation, and join against that table.  It's possible to make such queries fast.

Comment: While your comment is perfectly valid, it may not by enterely true that joining 2 tables would speed up things on small amounts of data. Some benchmarking might be needed to confirm that.

Answer (score -1):

This will do it.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid IN (26);
```

This should accomplish what you are looking for.

This can also be used to expand your selection.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE catid IN (26,27);
```

Comment: As a comment to @JamWaffles, the normalization of a database does make sense if you are building a decent EAV structure, but for simple data references it overcomplicates the overall idea.  You would then have 3 tables, the products, the categories, and the referenced links, you would then have to do an INNER JOIN on the aliased tables.

Comment: It won't work. You're trying to do: `select '2,4,26,33,46' in ('26')` which will always return 0. It might only work if catid begins with the value '26'

Comment: It will as long as the values exist in the column.  This will select any data where the catid is equal to 26.

Comment: Exactly, but catid doesn't just contain 26 in the question: "catid stores multiple categories id separated with commas"